# PyJWT doesnt work for rs256 in link format

Tags: python, encryption, jwt, cryptography

the algorithm in the header of the jwt is 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256',
but when pyjwt runs internally: `alg_obj = self.get_algorithm_by_name(alg)`
it raises:

```
NotImplementedError: Algorithm not supported
```

If i manually replace alg to 'RS256' during debug it works

Why doesn't the library recognize the algorithm in the link format?

Comment: maybe the one who is wrong is the other system author who used c#?

Comment: Why should it accept a link? The place to start for understanding a library is its documentation. [PyJWT's docs](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) say it's based on [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519), and RFC7519 refers to [RFC 7518](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518) for the algorithms, and there in [section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.1) is a nice table where you'll find `RS256` as well as many others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering an issue with PyJWT's handling of the JWT algorithm. The algorithm specified in the JWT header is 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256', which represents RSA with SHA-256 hashing. However, PyJWT expects algorithms to be specified in a different format, such as 'RS256' for RSA with SHA-256 hashing.

The reason PyJWT doesn't recognize the algorithm in the link format is likely due to its adherence to standard JWT algorithm identifiers, which are commonly represented as strings like 'RS256', 'HS256', etc., following the JWT specification.

To resolve the issue, you may need to ensure that the JWT algorithm in your token header conforms to the standard string representation expected by PyJWT. If you're in control of generating the JWT, consider using 'RS256' instead of the full URL. If you're receiving JWTs from an external source that uses the URL format, you may need to preprocess the JWT headers to translate the algorithm to the format recognized by PyJWT before validating or decoding the token.

Here's a summary of what you might do:

**Generate** JWTs: If you're generating JWTs, make sure to specify the algorithm as 'RS256' directly rather than using the URL format.

**Preprocess** JWTs: If you're receiving JWTs with algorithms specified in the URL format, preprocess the JWT header before passing it to PyJWT. You can write a function to translate the algorithm from the URL format to the standard string format recognized by PyJWT.

By adhering to the standard JWT algorithm identifiers, you can ensure compatibility with PyJWT and other JWT libraries that expect algorithms to be represented in a specific format.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: This reads like ChatGPT to me.